# Adding Opportunity Products Automatically by Process Builder

Tags: opportunity, process-builder, opportunity-lineitem

In Salesforce, I need to add Opportunity Products automatically for a new Opportunity. I have the product codes and prices in Opportunity layout, and need to add Opportunity Products automatically. (By Process Builder?)

Condition is

```
Product Code of Product =  Product Code (available on Opportunity)
Amount = 1
Sales Price = Order Amount (available on. opportunity)
```

Problem is, I need to add the opportunity Products

WHERE

```
Opportunity Product's "Product Code" is equal to "Product Code2" field on opportunity.
```

Comment: What's your problem so far?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a process builder on `Opportunity`.
2. Enable `only when a record is created`.
3. Specify criteria if any
4. In action section choose `Create a record` enter a name and select `Opportunity Product` as record type. Set the desired field values as below.

[image]

Comment: oopsie - looks like we forgot a few things like pricebook entry ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with Process Builder, but it is possible with Flow.

You would first need to use a Get Records element to find the corresponding Price Book Entry records and the use a Create Records element to insert the Opportunity Product records.